# Valid signing identity not found, I have tried other solutions, but doesn't seem to work

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I have looked at lodes of other posts about this and tried all of them, but I still keep getting this error...

I have opened key chain and there is a developer ID which is "valid" and a private key.

I have re-created several provisioning profile for the apps (selecting the app and device).

I am on a team based account, so I cant delete all the other provisioning profiles as other people may be using them, which is what a few solutions have said, but I have tried deleting all the provisioning profiles for the app and re-making them, but it still doesn't seem to work.

I am using xcode 4.6.3 and trying to install the app on iPad 6.1

Here are screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you select correct provisioning profiles in build settings? Also, did you try to relaunch Xcode? Xcode has been known to cache identity and profile settings for it's entire session until relauched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be your certificate is revoked and signed with a different key which you don't have, ask for the private key of newly signed certificate may be some has it.

Hope it works.

**Edit**

Your Developer profile needs to be recreated, and you can revoke your own developer certificate, it will not harm anyone else if you are in a team.

[image]

**Edit 2**

To create a new developer certificate do the following

1. Delete the old developer certificate.
2. Login to your developer portal developer.apple.com/iphone
3. Select Certificates, Identifiers and Profiles from iOS Developer
   Program menu on right.
4. Choose Certificates, then choose Development.
5. You will see your Developer certificate there, select that, then you
   will see Revoke option, press that and Revoke.
6. After revoking there you will see steps to create the Certificate
   follow that.
7. After creation you will need to update the Profile too with the new
   certificate.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work :/ I will post screen shots and show you all my screens

Comment: Your certificate doesn't contain any key, it needs to have a key see my edited answer

Comment: ohhh, I thought because there was a key above it was fine. How do I get this key?

Comment: I have the key and have imported it into keychain, how do I attach it to the developer?

Comment: Delete it in keychain or on developer portal?

Comment: Delete in Keychain, Revoke in portal